# Why doesn't this array_walk work to initialize an array in PHP?

Tags: php

I can't figure out why this doesn't work to initialize `$existingKeywordLookup`.

```
  $existingKeywords = $sharedSet->negativeKeywords;
  Yii::error("There are ".count($existingKeywords)." negative keywords.");
  $existingKeywordLookup = array(); // this is a lookup table to index the objects by the keyword attribute
  Yii::error("There are ".count($existingKeywordLookup)." existing keyword lookups.");
  array_walk($existingKeywords, function ($v) use ($existingKeywordLookup) { $existingKeywordLookup[$v->keyword] = $v; }); // create lookup table
  Yii::error("There are ".count($existingKeywordLookup)." existing keyword lookups.");
```

Logs

```
2015-12-15 22:30:53 [::1][1][eai6tdgr5fjlimpfdk27taloa4][error][application] There are 15 negative keywords.
2015-12-15 22:30:53 [::1][1][eai6tdgr5fjlimpfdk27taloa4][error][application] There are 0 existing keyword lookups.
2015-12-15 22:30:53 [::1][1][eai6tdgr5fjlimpfdk27taloa4][error][application] There are 0 existing keyword lookups.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `&` for the `use` clause.

```
array_walk($existingKeywords, function ($v) use (&$existingKeywordLookup) ...
```

Comment: Nice that you were able to answer your question. You can either mark your own answer as accepted to put closure to the question, or you can delete your question - your choice.

Comment: Aha, understood. Thank you for the information, Chloe!